# Create .gitconfig for chrooted users

Tags: debian, git

I have several chrooted users on my server, and I want to install git for specific users.

I block at the command :

```
git config --global user.name "user_name"
```

I use this command connected as the user, and I got this error :

```
error: could not lock config file /home/username/.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

I tried to create the file from root, and then put chmod 755 and chown username .gitconfig, but I get the error.

Is there a way to do this ?

Edit : This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908386/unable-to-create-gitconfig-file-for-user answers mine

Comment: I found my answer on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908386/unable-to-create-gitconfig-file-for-user

Comment: You can answer your own question if you now know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

git runs as user "git", with group "git", try to put your user in the git group or git in your user group.

Comment: This is wrong.  The `git` command runs as the user that executed it.  Even if it were true, adding the user to the git group would not help.  Adding git to the user's group *might* help depending on the file permissions, but these are not mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I think the problem is your /home/username are root:root because I guess you use sftp?

Answer (score -3):

use sudo before git command. Example: $sudo git config ...